# How ensure that some expected action is done whenever and wherever exception occurs?

Tags: c#, exception

I am doing some enhancements to existing code. And now I want to log one message whenever and wherever exception occurs.

I can add that message in catch/finally block but there are hundreds of catch blocks.

Can anyone suggest better approach to have the message logged whenever exceptions occurs at any part of the code in the assembly?

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to modify that blocks any way. Or comment them and use             AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (TopLevelErrorHandler); 
            Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;

Comment: Having a need for *really* strong logging is indeed inevitable when you induce random failure by catching all exceptions.  It doesn't stop there though, you'll also need to work on tools to repair the data corruption this causes.  Avoid all of this simply by deleting all of these try/catch statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second take:

A good approach is AOP with Postsharp.

I've used in many projects.

You can define an attribute that inherits from a base one of PostSharp API which permits you to intercept any method call of the one where you place your custom attribute.

If you put that attribute in any method, you'll be able to try/catch absolutely any method body, and, in the end, control exceptions and logging them.

You can achieve the same goal with Castle Dynamic Proxy, but this is a run-time solution, since you can create proxy classes with interceptors and instantiate your classes with a factory. Obviously, this is consuming more resources.

Postsharp performs IL weaving, meaning that your interceptors will be injected in your actual code in compile-time, so, you don't loose run-time performance.

Summarizing, you can create a "LogAttribute" and place it in any method you want to log or do things if an exception happens.

Comment: + 1 : Very Good Option. Thought of that but I've never really used AOP in .Net yet. Though it has a certain development cost, don't know if the asker of the question is willing to bear that.

Comment: Actually Postsharp has a community edition, so he should has no cost for using it. I believe that Postsharp is well-documented and it's extremly easy to use, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting issue when you have legacy code you have to deal with.
If you *REALLY* do not want to change your catch blocks, then I might suggest a workaround :
 

One option you got is writing a`LoggedExceptionInterface`or whatever, and implement a`LogEvent`in it, and then audit all of your code scanning for handled exception types and redefening them by adding your interface to them.
For example you would replace `IOException` by `LoggedIOException` where the latter inherits the first, implementing the `LoggedExceptionInterface` on top.

Of course, this might turn out to be heavier than changing catch blocks individually;The choice is yours.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be good solution since in future too, I will not have to expect other developers to remember every time to do some definite action at the end of every catch block!

Comment: Don't forget to upvote (and/or mark as answered if satisfied) ;-) Considering AOP as advised by Mathias might be a cleaner/fancier (though a bit heavier and less straightforward) option

Comment: The magic of IL weaving is just that AOP becomes lighty because is compile-time and behind the scenes, I really like that approach (you noted it, for sure haha)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>For sure, you've last-chance exception handlers.</strike>

ASP.NET has it in the HttpApplication, with the Error event (most of the times in the Global ASAX if you're not using an HTTP Module).

WPF and Silverlight have then in the Application.

And Windows Forms can use the AppDomain.UnhandledException event.

Mika Jacobi is right, this is a bad answer. Sorry for that.

Comment: This proposition does NOT work. What he is looking for is something to ADD to EXISTING try/catch blocks

Comment: That's how I do it. This will not get the handled exceptions.

Comment: @Michael : How to bypass handled exceptions with AppDomain.UnhandledException then ?